# Using REGEX in Java for splitting a string

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I written a code to split the following string

> (((OPERATING_CARRIER='AB') OR (OPERATING_CARRIER='EY') OR
>   ((OPERATING_CARRIER='VA') AND ((FLIGHT_NO=604) OR ((FLIGHT_NO=603) AND
>   (STOCK='9W'))))))

into following array of strings

> OPERATING_CARRIER='AB'
>   OPERATING_CARRIER='EY'
>   OPERATING_CARRIER='VA'
>   FLIGHT_NO=604
>   FLIGHT_NO=603
>   STOCK='9W'

The code is

```
String sa="(((OPERATING_CARRIER='AB') OR (OPERATING_CARRIER='EY') OR ((OPERATING_CARRIER='VA') AND ((FLIGHT_NO=604) OR ((FLIGHT_NO=603) AND (STOCK='9W'))))))";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s*=\\s*(?:'[^']+'|\\d+)").matcher(sa);
        //System.out.println("contains "+sa.contains("((("));
        Stack<String> in_cond = new Stack<String>();
        Iterator<String> iter = in_cond.iterator();
        String new_sa=sa;
        System.out.println("Indivisual conditions are as follows : ");
        while(m.find()) {
            String aMatch = m.group();
            // add aMatch to match list...
            System.out.println(aMatch);
            in_cond.push(aMatch);
        }
        System.out.println("End of Indivisual conditions");
```

But now in the input string, the "=" can also be "<>" or"<" or ">" or "LIKE"
eg :

> (((OPERATING_CARRIER<>'AB') OR (OPERATING_CARRIER LIKE'EY') OR
>   ((OPERATING_CARRIER='VA') AND ((FLIGHT_NO<604) OR ((FLIGHT_NO>603) AND
>   (STOCK='9W'))))))

What changes need to be done in the regex?

Answer (score 3):

I guess there are simpler (and more *readable*) ways to do this :).

Use `replaceAll()` to replace all braces with empty String. Next split based on either `AND` or `OR`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "(((OPERATING_CARRIER='AB') OR (OPERATING_CARRIER='EY') OR ((OPERATING_CARRIER='VA') AND ((FLIGHT_NO=604) OR ((FLIGHT_NO=603) AND (STOCK='9W'))))))";
    String[] arr = s.replaceAll("[()]+","").split("\\s+(OR|AND)\\s+");
    for (String str : arr) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
OPERATING_CARRIER='AB'
OPERATING_CARRIER='EY'
OPERATING_CARRIER='VA'
FLIGHT_NO=604
FLIGHT_NO=603
STOCK='9W'
```

Comment: This Works perfectly for me . Just a doubt  now, I have the strings OPERATING_CARRIER<>'AB' , OPERATING_CARRIER LIKE 'EY', FLIGHT_NO>603 in a  string array and i have to split them into OPERATING_CARRIER,<>,AB and so on , how would i do that

Comment: @jason - I believe you were asking for a perfect solution.:P

Comment: Hi Folks I have used the following code and it works just fine for me:             `String input= "name = 'name_1' AND in_stock IN {'in_stock_1','in_stock_2'} AND ( price BETWEEN '01-jan-2015' and '31-may-2015' OR price = 'price_3' )";   String sa =input;
       String[] arr = sa.replaceAll("[()]+","").split("\\s*(\\sOR|\\sAND)\\s*");
       for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
       {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
       }
       `